# Intellisense doesn't work in visualstudio 2010 between <% %> tags in views

Tags: visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller

hi 
I have a problem with intellisense in aspx or ascx files , it doesn't work between <% %> tags like mvc tags. is there any solution to solve it, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Found the answer by my self
this problem was made by our source controller (SVN) , I Deleted the project folder completely and then I got the code again by svn checkout and the problem is now solved